# Where are the installation directories for homebrew?

Tags: homebrew

Where does Homebrew install it's software?

I've installed Maven with Homebrew and searching for the Maven installation directory, so that I can set `MAVEN_HOME`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**brew** installs binary in separate directories inside `/usr/local` dir. Then makes symlink inside `/usr/local/bin`. To get real path to binary type for example this (for `tree` command):

```
ls -l /usr/local/bin/ | grep tree
```

Output:

```
lrwxr-xr-x  1 slozo  admin    29 23 lip 15:06 tree -> ../Cellar/tree/1.7.0/bin/tree
```

So my `tree` command is located in `/usr/local/Cellar/tree/1.7.0/bin/tree`

Answer (score 1):

Homebrew installs to `brew --prefix` (which is different for different CPU architectures).

Not sure `MAVEN_HOME` is still relevant nowadays, but if you need to set it, use

```
export MAVEN_HOME="$(brew --prefix)/opt/maven/libexec"
```

This will ensure that it will work both on Intel and ARM Macs, it also is independent of the installed Maven version (because Homebrew ensures that `$(brew --prefix)/opt/maven` always points to the latest version).

Answer (score -2):

Homebrew now installs to `/opt/homebrew`.  You can find the Maven 3.8.6 binary at `/Cellar/maven/3.8.6/bin/mvn`, with a symlink at `/opt/homebrew/bin/mvn`, for example.

Note that you can always discover the location of an executable on the `PATH` with `which <name>`.  `which mvn` would show the symlink above, and `ls -l $(which mvn)` would show the actual location.

Finally: For Maven specifically, you can get its home directory by running `mvn -v`.  It shows `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/maven/3.8.6/libexec` in this case.